# How change value of nested array in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out width update value of item in nested array of reducer and change value.

Its my reducer state:

```
let initialState = {
   data: {
     users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'a'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'b'
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

and I want to change name of item in data.users but I can't access there

How can I do this?

I tried this

```
case SET_NAME:
        return {
          ...state,
          users: state.data.users((item, i) =>
            item.id == action.payload.id ? { ...item, value: action.payload.value} : null
          )
        };
```

but I can't access the users

Comment: what do you get when you log state.data.users before return statement

Comment: A blank object in root state not in data

Answer (score 4):

Have a spread party...

```
case SET_NAME:
  return {
    ...state,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      users: [
        ...(state.data.users.map(user =>
          user.id === action.payload.id
          ? { ...user, value: action.payload.value }
          : user
        ))
      ]
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are 3 issues with your reducer:

- `data` is missing in your returned object
- the call to the map function of the `users` array is missing
- your example would set any item which is not matching the id of the action to `null` instead of preserving it.

You probably ment to do this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    data: {
        ...state.data,
        users: state.data.users.map(item =>
            item.id == action.payload.id ? { ...item, value: action.payload.value } : item
        )
    }
};
```

for this action:

```
{
   type: SET_NAME,
   payload: { id: 1, value: 'test' }
}
```

the resulting state will be this:

```
{
   data: {
     users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'a',
            value: 'test'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'b'
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

If you want to set the name to the `value` from the action, you can just override it in the reducer. In that case the whole reducer would be:

```
return {
    ...state,
    data: {
        ...state.data,
        users: state.data.users.map(item =>
            item.id == action.payload.id ? { ...item, name: action.payload.value } : item
        )
    }
};
```

and the result state for the above action would be this:

```
{
   data: {
     users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'test'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'b'
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return {
    ...state,
    data: {
            // add "state.data" if there is any other data than the users 
            // array that you don't want to be removed or changed  
            ...state.data,
            users: state.data.users((item, i) =>
                item.id == action.payload.id
                ? { ...item, value: action.payload.value }
                : null
            )
        }
```

If it didn't, this should work:

```
// Will loop over the existing users array in the state and return an array.
const updatedUsers = state.data.users.map((item, i) => {
            // If the item exist and matches the id of the payload,
            // it will update it
            if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                item.value = action.payload.value;
            }
            return item;
        });

        // And here is a console log to see the updated array
        console.log(updatedUsers)

        return {
            ...state,
            // This is how you update a nested array
            data: { ...state.data, users: updatedUsers }
        };
```